# Google Calendar event buttons -- Mobile version

Tags: events, mobile, google-calendar-api

I've created a mobile site that displays events retrieved from a Google Calendar. I would like to display a button on each event that allows the user to add the event to their own Google Calendar.

Google Calendar provides a simple way to do this with HTML snippets:
(http://www.google.com/googlecalendar/event_publisher_guide_detail.html)

The url takes parameters so that you can populate the add event form. Here's an example:
https://www.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=Brunch+at+Java+Cafe&dates=20060415T180000Z/20060415T190000Z&location=Java+Cafe,+San+Francisco,+CA&details=Try+our+Saturday+brunch+special:%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3EFrench+toast+with+fresh+fruit%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3EYum!&trp;=true&sprop;=+website:http://www.javacafebrunches.com&sprop;=name:Jave+Cafe&gsessionid=OK&sf=true&output=xml

Unfortunately I can't find a mobile equivalent of this page. If you go to the page with Android, it asks if you want to use the mobile version, but because there isn't one, it repeatedly displays the dialog until you finally cancel the dialog.

Does anyone know of a mobile version of this page, or suggest another way to do it? (Ideally without AJAX as it's causing some offline caching issues on iPhone in app mode).

Answer (score 7):

I've been doing some research on this myself and I've come close, but I'm not 100% there yet.  Here's a sample URL of a mobile "share event" link:

http://www.google.com/calendar/gp#~calendar:view=e&bm=1&action=TEMPLATE&text=Halloween+Party+2011&dates=20111101/20111202&details=Description&location=Millennial+Media&trp=false

It opens up the mobile version of Google Calendar and pre-populates it with details about the event your sharing.

The only problem I've encountered is when you're not already logged into Google Calendar.  It takes you to the log in page, which is fine, but then after you log in it takes you to the home screen instead of the event entry page.

If you find or already found an answer to this, let me know.

~ TJ

Comment: Any update on this here? I'm running into the same problem trying to add calendar event support to a mobile web app. It's funky that Android doesn't support iCal out of the box in the first place, and even more poopy that there isn't formal support (or more graceful degradation on the device side) for adding calendar events to mobile devices.

Comment: Where's the document ? I can't find those even the render?action=template

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by document.  Its a url.  The query string arguments prepopulates the "Add Event" form on the Google Calendar page.

Unfortunately, I don't have any more updates to this.  The research got scrapped for more pressing priorities.  This was about all I could find.

Comment: I think he meant: where is the documentation for this URL?